# AWS Cognito - obtain tokens after successful signup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We are integrating with AWS Cognito via:
`client (browser) -> server -> AWS Cognito`. We are doing this as we want to set a `httpOnly` cookie for security reasons.

We are signing up the user via `signUp` and `confirmSignUp` (SMS code) APIs which is called in our server. Is it possible to obtain the user's access token after `confirmSignUp` without having the user go through the whole authentication (username + password + sms) step? I've looked for admin APIs or other APIs to do this but couldn't find one that'd do what I'm looking for.

Comment: Had you found anything for this? Thanks in advance